# Ionic 3 : How do I know if I have access to the Internet on a network (wifi or mobile)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to know how I can find out if I have internet access on a network, because I could be connected to a wifi network without having internet access for example but how do I know?

I use ionic-native/network but that's not enough!

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.network.onConnect().subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });

  this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe((data) =>  {
    console.log(data);
  });

  this.network.onchange().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

Because as you can see, it only detects if I'm connected to a network, but it doesn't know if the network has internet access.

I hope you can help me:)

Answer (score 1):

The way you would test this is to make an HTTP request to a server, and if it responds with 2XX, then your device is connected. You can "poll" (keep sending requests at a regular interval) to see when connectivity is dropped, but I recommend you do this against your own server so you don't anger another company :)

I've used this plugin before, and you're correct in your assessment that it's rather useless in terms of checking internet connection, but this method (sending regular HTTP requests) is rather common.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! 
Indeed I thought about this idea but I am saying that it was not a good way to do it but I do not see any other way to know.

It's a pity that ionic doesn't allow you to know natively, because my phone is able to know if a network with internet access or not because if the phone knows that the network doesn't have internet access I think there must be a way to get this information.

Comment: In Ionic, there is not. In Capacitor, you _may_ be able to but I haven't used it enough yet (here are docs for you to try: https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/network) I'll ask around and report back.

Comment: Thank you I will also go and see on my side:)

Comment: I'm late here, but for what it's worth, capacitor's Network plugin also does the same.. it's useless if you want to check if the connected network has an active internet connection.